# sqlite performs very slow for map tiles

Tags: sqlite

It's my first time with sqlite and I wrote a simple database for storing and retrieving map tiles.
Here is the sqlite data base:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tiles (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, X INTEGER NOT NULL, Y INTEGER NOT NULL, Zoom INTEGER NOT NULL, Type INTEGER NOT NULL,Date TEXT)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TilesData (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT fk_Tiles_id REFERENCES Tiles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, Tile BLOB NULL)

CREATE TRIGGER fki_TilesData_id_Tiles_id BEFORE INSERT ON [TilesData] FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'insert on table TilesData violates foreign key constraint fki_TilesData_id_Tiles_id') WHERE (SELECT id FROM Tiles WHERE id = NEW.id) IS NULL; END

CREATE TRIGGER fku_TilesData_id_Tiles_id BEFORE UPDATE ON [TilesData] FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'update on table TilesData violates foreign key constraint fku_TilesData_id_Tiles_id') WHERE (SELECT id FROM Tiles WHERE id = NEW.id) IS NULL; END

CREATE TRIGGER fkdc_TilesData_id_Tiles_id BEFORE DELETE ON Tiles FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DELETE FROM TilesData WHERE TilesData.id = OLD.id; END
```

Here is the insert operation:

```
INSERT INTO Tiles(X, Y, Zoom, Type,Date) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?,?);
INSERT INTO TilesData(id, Tile) VALUES((SELECT last_insert_rowid()), ?);
```

Here is the read operation:

```
SELECT Tile FROM TilesData WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM Tiles WHERE X=%1 AND Y=%2 AND Zoom=%3 AND Type=%4)
```

The problem is, when the database is small the read is still very fast(around 20ms), but when the database becomes larger (around 15000 rows), the read access becomes very slow (around 4000ms).
Am I doing anything wrong? Any suggestions to improve the performance?

Answer (score 2):

if you want for Android You can use also noSQL solution for speed. For example [Couchbase](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/training/build-first-android-app/)

Comment: look at , nosql [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) is very speed more than SQL , or other SQL, For exaple MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle etc. SQlite designed for little data.